# File reader is replacing characters whose index is greater than 127 with question marks

Tags: javascript, html, file, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to make a program that is able to read a UTF-8 encoded file containing characters with indexes from 0 to 255. I plan to have the program operate by having the user pick a file from their computer, and once the file is selected, the program reads its text contents. However, I am encountering a problem; the characters in the text content of the file that have an index greater than 127 seem to be getting replaced by question marks that look like this: �. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type=file style=font-size:20px onchange="next(this)"></input>
<div id=data></div>
```

Javascript:

```
async function next(elem){
var content=await elem.files[0].text()
document.getElementById("data").innerText=content;
}
```

Please may you help me find a way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Can you check if logging the text on the console show the same � characters? If it does it may be the file is not encoded in utf-8.

Comment: @traktor thank you. This was indeed the problem, as the file was encoded in windows-1252 instead of utf-8. I changed the meta charset to windows-1252 and my program was able to display the file contents correctly.